# Want to run JMeter test script for infinite loop but not working

Tags: windows, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, health-monitoring

I want to do server health monitoring on my localhost windows server.

Why if I want to extract the monitoring for infinite loop count but the test stop at second 9?
[image]

[image]

I really don't understand why I didn't get the test running for infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

A [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) itself won't be executed, as per [JMeter Test Elements Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder)

> ```
> 0. Configuration elements
> 1. Pre-Processors
> 2. Timers
> 3. Sampler
> 4. Post-Processors (unless SampleResult is null)
> 5. Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)
> 6. Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)
> ```

The key point is `unless SampleResult is null` so you need to have a [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) to see the results of a Listener, if you don't have any Samplers in the Thread Group - none of the Listeners will be executed.

So enable your HTTP Request sampler or if you don't want to do anything like sending a request but see the charts add a [Dummy Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) to your test plan and it should start working normally.

Comment: Thank you sir, this is very helpful. I tried to add a Dummy Sampler and it works